# download source code before define commit from github

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to download source code from a github public project before a define commit.
There is one project structure of which I want to get but it will be easier to understand it commit by commit. I can see it, but I want to download and test step by step.

FOUND:
[How to get certain commit from GitHub project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832770/get-certain-commit-from-github-project)

Comment: Just check it out, then play with it locally. you're thinking about it wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832770/get-certain-commit-from-github-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you clone the repository, you can do `git log` to see a list of all commits on the master branch and then `git checkout <SHA1>` to move to any commit where `<SHA1>` is the string of characters on lines such as

```
commit 04ff4a3216988821fa69e679d105346f179e9c7d
```